# Accessing Cloudant using nodejs nano

Tags: node.js, cloudant

Is there a gist which I can follow to use to connect to cloudant using nano / nodejs. Or, is there any other library which I can use to connect from nodejs to cloudant.  Here is the error I encounter, when i try to connect.

```
  description: 'one of _writer, _creator is required for this request',
```

Here is how my code looks

```
// require nano, point it at cloudant's root
var config = require('config');
var nano = require('nano')({url: config.cloudant.url})
    , username = config.cloudant.username
    , userpass = config.cloudant.password
    , cookies = {}
    , callback = console.log // this would normally be some callback

  ;


nano.auth(username, userpass, function (err, body, headers) {
    if (err) {
        return callback(err);
    }

    if (headers && headers['set-cookie']) {
        cookies['user'] = headers['set-cookie'];
    }

    callback(null, "it worked");
});




var db = require('nano')({
    'url': config.cloudant.url + '/' + config.cloudant.database,
    'cookie': cookies['user']
});
```

After this, when i try to connect - i get the error

```
var db = require('nano')({
    'url': config.cloudant.url + '/' + config.cloudant.database,
    'cookie': cookies['user']
});

var doc = {"hello": "world"};

db.insert(doc, function (err, body, headers) {
    if (err) {
        return callback(err);
    }

    // change the cookie if couchdb tells us to
    if (headers && headers['set-cookie']) {
        cookies['user'] = headers['set-cookie'];
    }

    callback(null, "it worked");
});
```

Comment: did you resolve this issue, or are you still looking for help?

Comment: @SHC: Yes this is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this https://github.com/cloudant/nodejs-cloudant . It is a wrapper over `nano` to directly connect with cloudant.